# How to show $h\equiv 1\bmod{(p-1)(q-1)(r-1)}\implies a^h\equiv a \bmod{pqr}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $p, q, r$ be distinct primes,
let $n = pqr$, and
let $m = (p − 1)(q − 1)(r − 1).$

Show that for any $a\in \mathbb Z$ and $h\in \mathbb N$, we have
$(h\equiv 1\mod m)$ implies $(a^h\equiv a \mod n).$

I know I need to approach this with Fermat's Little Theorem, but am not sure what to do.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933), and [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) (and fix your typoS in the title).

Comment: Thanks for sharing that! Sorry pretty new to the platform, plus I'm also new to this topic, so appreciate that!

Comment: Are you familiar with Chinese Remainder Theorem? If so, can you state how you'd apply it to this problem? (Just how you've get started is fine, not expecting that you'd fully solve it)

Comment: would we need to show that 
  $a^h$ satisfies the congruences

$a^ h ≡a(modp)$,
$a ^ h≡a(modq)$,
$a^ h ≡a(modr)$,
​

Comment: @RyanJoshi Yup! Do you see why that is true?

Comment: Yep thanks! (since n = pqr right?) thus if we prove each of those it gives us what we want

Comment: $a^{m(p-1)}\equiv1^m\pmod p$.

Comment: Special case $\,e=1\, $ in the Theorem in the linked dupe.